# How to find scrollview scrolled position dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

*Hi,I am new to android.my requirement is when user scrolling the scroll view,based on scrolled height i want to change images on screen. for this i want the event which will call immediately when scroll is changing,and once user reach end position i want set it to first position programatically. it is continuous loop.*

Answer (score 1):

You may use the listView instead of scrollView. So you can use onScrollChangeListener.